# How to assert the video actions using java?

Tags: java, appium

1. I am writing automation test cases for video related testing
2. My scenario is, I will click play button to play the video and I need to assert the video is playing or not
3. How can I able to assert the video is getting  played or paused?
4. I don't know whether it is possible  to assert this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Using Timer**: When you click on play button lets start one timer equal to the length of video and check the time (On your Player) with the timer if they equal it means your video runs completely.

   If Timer > Playing Time - Video is still playing

---

2. **Using Buttons** :You can also check for the Icons (Play Button/Pause Button) If in your App After clicking on play button if it changes to pause button It means your video starts playing. When again it become Play button it means Video stops playing (Similar to youtube player).

---

3. **For Assertion :** as I stated above you can Assert whether Timers are equal or Buttons enabled or disabled also you can use Progress Bar of video.

---

4. **Using Screenshots :** You can take the screenshot of completed video than compare it with screenshot taken after running video.( for that you can integrate third party tool like Applitools )

---

5. [applitools.com](https://applitools.com/)

---

6. Following code snippet shows how to use Timer

   ```
    long startTime = 0,stopTime = 0,elapsedTime = 0;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ```

   /*Do some action like play video you can apply logic like using do while and compare start time with video playing time */

   ```
    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    elapsedTime/=1000;
   ```

Comment: How to start and stop timer in java? I need one clarification, I am playing a video, after video get stopped, how can I  stop timer, after video playing got stopped.